Is there a non-deprecated replacement for NSCursor.currentSystemCursor?
I'm writing a macOS application that needs to get an image of the current system cursor. I can use NSCursor.currentSystemCursor but it's marked as deprecated starting with macOS 15. Is there a supported replacement?

Actually it's marked as deprecated since(!) macOS 15 (Sequoia)

You are correct -- I misread the doc page!
